# Slideshow too fast when coming back from another tab

Tags: javascript, slideshow

The slideshow on the Homepage is too fast when coming back from another tab. I tried a few other solutions from the site but it did not work in my case. Hope someone can really help. Thanks much.

Here's the Javascript:

> Blockquote

```
    $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    setInterval(function() {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
   .fadeOut(1000)
   .next()
   .fadeIn(1000)
   .end()
   .appendTo('#slideshow');

   }, 5000);
```

> Blockquote

HTML Code:

> Blockquote

```
    <div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src="abc.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="def.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="ghi.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="jkl.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

> Blockquote
>
> Blockquote

```
     /*Slideshow */
     #slideshow > div {
     width: 970px;
     height: 500px;
     display: block;
     float: left;
     position: absolute;
     top: 200px;
     right: auto;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     margin-left: 15px;
     line-height: 180px;
```

}

> Blockquote

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: Just posted the HTML code. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Just needed more details to be able to help.

Comment: Also, what does your CSS look like?

Comment: Edited to include CSS too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's too fast, just increase the time to `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()`. Use `$(window).focus()` and `$(window).blur()` to check when a user left the tab and clear the slideshow interval. When the user comes back, set the interval again.

```js
 $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

    var slideshow = setInterval(function() {
      beginSlideshow();
    }, 5000);
    function beginSlideshow(){
      $('#slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(2000)//time doubled from 1000 to 2000 milliseconds
    .next()
    .fadeIn(2000)//time doubled from 1000 to 2000 milliseconds
    .end()
    .appendTo('#slideshow');
    }
   $(window).focus(function() {
     if (slideshow==null){
       //Use came back to the tab
      slideshow = setInterval(function(){
       beginSlideshow();
      }, 5000);
     }
   });

 $(window).blur(function() {
   //User left tab
   clearInterval(slideshow);
   slideshow = null;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src="test9/SitePage_9dArip.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test9/SitePage_9dCand.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test9/SitePage_9dfinalOK.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="test9/SitePage_9dPrav.png">
        </div>
    </div>
```

JSFiddle：http://jsfiddle.net/1vk3fqr8/3/

Comment: Otherwise fine. Too fast only when coming back from another tab/window.

Comment: @user256508 So would it help to stop the slideshow when the user switches tabs?

Comment: I guess it would help and start from where it left off when the user comes back to the tab. What changes do I make in the code? Thanks.

Comment: @user256508 I added the necessary changes.

Comment: You just made my day!! Thanks so much for the changes you made, it works perfectly ...much much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: @user256508 No problem.